# Apollo Client: writeFragment or readFragment when updating cache?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

In the `update` hook of useMutation, Apollo's documentation recommends using `writeFragment` to get an internal reference to a newly added object. I find this peculiar, as that object already exists in the cache. So I tested it with `readFragment` and sure enough, it works well. Is there a preference to using `writeFragment` over `readFragment` in this use case?

### Example 1:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates

```
const [addTodo] = useMutation(ADD_TODO, {
    update(cache, { data: { addTodo } }) {
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          todos(existingTodos = []) {
            const newTodoRef = cache.writeFragment({
              data: addTodo,
              fragment: gql`
                fragment NewTodo on Todo {
                  id
                  type
                }
              `
            });
            return [...existingTodos, newTodoRef];
          }
        }
      });
```

Excerpt from that page:

> With the help of cache.writeFragment we get an internal reference to
> the added todo, then store that reference in the ROOT_QUERY.todos
> array.

### Example 2:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#example-updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation

```
const [addComment] = useMutation(ADD_COMMENT, {
  update(cache, { data: { addComment } }) {
    cache.modify({
      fields: {
        comments(existingCommentRefs = [], { readField }) {
          const newCommentRef = cache.writeFragment({
            data: addComment,
            fragment: gql`
              fragment NewComment on Comment {
                id
                text
              }
            `
          });
          return [...existingCommentRefs, newCommentRef];
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Excerpt from that page:

> the comment was already added to the cache by useMutation.
> Consequently, cache.writeFragment returns a reference to the existing
> object.

I also posted this question on Apollo Client's discussion board (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/discussions/7515), but didn't get a response there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of using `writeFragment` over `readFragment` when fetching an item from cache is explained here (excerpt from https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#example-updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation):

> If you call writeFragment with an options.data object that the cache is able to identify, based on its __typename and primary key fields, you can avoid passing options.id to writeFragment.
>
> Whether you provide options.id explicitly or let writeFragment figure it out using options.data, writeFragment returns a Reference to the identified object.
>
> This behavior makes writeFragment a good tool for obtaining a Reference to an existing object in the cache, which can come in handy
> when writing an update function for useMutation

This is counterintuitive as the name `writeFragment` implies that it's for writing to the cache and not reading from it, but it seems to be the recommended best practice.